# How do I keep the last 4 full backups

Tags: linux, backup, dump

I have a CentOS server running with backup made to an external HDD.

I run a full backup everyday at 4am and incremental backups every 2 hour. I am keeping the last 30 days backups which is achieved by running a cron job every day at 6am which clears all files older than 30 days:

```
0  6  *  *  *  root /bin/find /mnt/hp/backups -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Recently my HDD is getting out of space so I am changing my backup strategy to only keep 4 full backups for last 4 weeks. Eg, full backup of the every Monday.

How do I write a script to keep last 4 full backup for the past 4 weeks? I am using dump to perform the backups

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

- Take full weekly backup with a unique name prefix like `weeklybkp_`
- Then put a script like following in cron after every weekly backup.

> ```
> DELETEMORETHAN=$(ls -1 weeklybkp* | wc -l)
> if [ "$DELETEMORETHAN" -gt 4 ] ; then
>    COUNT=$(echo "$DELETEMORETHAN - 4" | bc -l)
>    rm -rvf $(ls -1t weeklybkp* | tail -${COUNT})
> fi
> ```